# I want to implement this active inductor design in my circuit

Tags: rf, inductor, cmos, power-amplifier, virtuoso

I'm trying to use an active inductor instead of the inductor in my class e power amplifier, however, I'm having difficulties in getting the required values for the parameters, Cds, Cgs, Cgd, and Ceq, for example. I have the SPICE model for the components in the library that I'm using inside of Cadence Virtuoso.

[image]

[image]

The article in the screenshots: [A 29-dBm OIP3 Dual-Stage Power Amplifier with Analog Pre-Distorter in 0.18 µm CMOS for IoT Transceiver](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338188528_A_29-dBm_OIP3_Dual-Stage_Power_Amplifier_with_Analog_Pre-Distorter_in_018_m_CMOS_for_IoT_Transceiver)

Comment: Edit: I apologize Ceq is already known from the article which is Ceq = C4 +C5 + Cgs3 + Cgs4

Comment: I don't know how Cadence-Pspice does it, but I know in LTspice if you run an `.op` analysis under your desired DC conditions you can view the small-signal "linearized" parameters for Cgs Cgd etc. by looking at the SPICE Error Log (CTRL+L).  Regardless, it'll depend on the specific model/subcircuit you're using for the PMOS transistors.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to create a .scs file with a name of your choice, and then write in it:

```
save *:oppoint
```

This will save the operating point for every small signal contained in your spice model (e.g. cgs, cgd, gm, etc). The * means you'll save all components that have an operating point associated with it (probably including PDK passive components that might be included in your schematic).

Something to watch out for is if your schemyos large. When this is so, the simulator will take a lot of time to save the operating point of each component. If you're only interested in a few, you can just replace the * by the name of your component (e.g M1 for a transistor), and get only those you need.

In addition, you can also only save some of the small signal parameters instead of all. To that end, replace "oppoint" by the parameter you want to save, such as "cgs","gm",etc.

To have your simulator use this file, save them in the Model Library Setup as an extra file. Or save it as an stimulus file.

To retrieve the data, you can simply go to your results browser, look under dc or dc-dc folder for your component name and you should be able to find the saved ops.

Otherwise you could use the `getData("component_name:small_signal_param")` expression for your outputs to plot them.